# How do we get rid of the error 'TypeError: 'module' object is not callable', while calling the Cloud Trail API using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

I am getting the TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error while calling CloudTrail API using the below code:

```
response = client.lookup_events(
    LookupAttributes=[
        {
            'AttributeKey':'Username',
            'AttributeValue': 'user1'
        },
    ],
    StartTime=datetime(2020, 4, 4),
    EndTime=datetime(2020, 6, 1),
    MaxResults=123
)
```

Can someone help me to proceed with this

Comment: Which line did the error occur on?  We expect to see the full traceback message.  I suspect it was actually one of the calls to `datetime()`, rather than anything to do with your API; that call is only valid if you did `from datetime import datetime` or similar.  If you just did `import datetime`, that name refers to the module rather than the class contained in the module.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with your suggestion!